# How to play .wav files on IE?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, internet-explorer, audio

I am developing a html5 - angularjs application.

Where I need to play .wav files being fetched from server on UI.

This functionality needs to be supported on all browsers.

It is working fine with Chrome, firefox, safari.

But on IE, I am receiving error.

1. If I try

   ```
   <audio controls>
      <source src="example.wav">
   </audio>
   ```

Error - in audio tag it displays Invalid source. But no console error.

2. If I try

   ```
   <audio controls src="example.wav"></audio>
   ```

Error - in audio tag it displays

> Invalid source

Also in browser console, it displays

> MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type.

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [supported media formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) page?

Comment: I need to support IE9+

Comment: Is there any plugin with which we can support wav files on IE? Any alternative way to audio tag?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem and it's caused by IE not supporting .wav files in HTML5 (which makes no sense, but, oh well).

I came up with a Javascript function that handles this; I included a call to the function in the `<a>` that was triggering the audio to play; this way, the function fires, but does nothing in non-IE browsers, but in IE, it plays it and fails pretty gracefully in the HTML5 audio player.

```
function playWavFileInIE(src){
    if(/msie/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /trident/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        var origPlayer = document.getElementById('currentWavPlayer');
        if(origPlayer){
            origPlayer.src = '';
            origPlayer.outerHtml = '';
            document.body.removeChild(origPlayer);
            delete origPlayer;
        }
        var newPlayer = document.createElement('bgsound');
        newPlayer.setAttribute('id', 'currentWavPlayer');
        newPlayer.setAttribute('src', src);
        document.body.appendChild(newPlayer);
        return false;
    }
}
```

All of the lines in the `if(origPlayer){...}` block appear to be needed; without any one of those, I ended up with the .wav remaining on the page and it steadily became an echo with every click. I'm sure there's a logical explanation, but...I was in a hurry.

Comment: can you create snippet for this? I can't make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a possibility for you, convert the **.wav** files on the server to **.mp3**.

This worked for me in audio elements of a site that I was working on.

.MP3 file format seems to be more widely supported than .WAV (see links below):

- https://caniuse.com/#search=wav
- https://caniuse.com/#search=mp3